# Why does this searching fail?

Tags: c++

I have just learnt C++ for a very short time, and in an assignment 
I am trying to find a particular target in a 2-dimensional array as follows:

```
bool simsearch(int array[22][22], int target, int n){
    bool result = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a < n + 1; a++){
        for (int b = 1; b < n + 1; b++){
            if (array[a][b] == target)
                result = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and use it like:

```
if(simsearch(substitute, 6, size) == 0){
        cout << "**Warning**" << '\n';
    }
```

But, the warning output is always there even if the target is in the array.
What is the underlying problem in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Array indexing in C/C++ goes between 0 and `n-1` (not between 1 and `n`).

Comment: Why do you use `0` and `1` for `bool`, why not `false` and `true`?

Comment: Sorry to mislead all of you, but n does not represent the size of the array, thus the underlying problem is not the numbers, but thank you for all of the answers and I have solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool simsearch(int array[22][22], int target, int n){
    bool result = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < n ; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < n; b++){
            if (array[a][b] == target){
                result = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(result) break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This should work. Use brackets and conditions properly

Comment: Why are people giving -1 ?? Please state the reason too !

Comment: I just edited in his answer so that he can understand his errors better. This is not my coding style!

Comment: But two breaks look not very well.

Comment: Once again..I just helped him in correcting his code so that he can realize where his fault was.. He asked about the problem in the code not any optimizations..I also know there can be many better ways of doing this.

Comment: +1 for this.  It should be noted that failure to use braces correctly was one of the major causes of the recent iOS bug that pretty much neutered their SSL implementation.  Go to this web page: http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/ and search for "MISTAKE" to see the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

Indices of arrays start from 0 and if an array has n elements then the highest index is n-1.

Rewrite the function the following way

```
bool simsearch( const int array[22][22], int target, int n )
{
    bool found = false;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n && !found; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n && !found; j++ )
        {
            if ( array[i][j] == target ) found = true;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Or

```
bool simsearch( const int array[22][22], int target, int n )
{
    bool found = false;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n && !found; i++ )
    {
        int j = 0;

        while ( j < n && array[i][j] != target ) j++;

        found = j != n; 
    }

    return found;
}
```

I hope that the argument for n is always equal to 22.:)

Another approach is the following

```
template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>

bool simsearch( const T ( &a )[M][N], const T &value )
{
    bool found = false;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M && !found; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j < N && !( a[i][j] == value ) ) ++j;

        found = j != N;
    }

    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to notice over here:-

```
for (int a = 1; a < n + 1; a++)
```

If n represents size here ( which seems from call to this function) then this you need to change. Array of size 10 must be indexed from 0 to 9.

Second thing rather than returning integer

```
return result;
```

you can return true OR false.